# Is it safe to use credit Karma?

Tags: credit-score

Is that safe to share my credit information with credit Karma, to have my credit score? How they use this information?

Comment: Check this out   http://www.ftc.gov/enforcement/cases-proceedings/132-3091/credit-karma-inc

Comment: @DumbCoder makes them pretty secure now after all of those orders

Answer (score 1):

I've used credit karma for sometime now and have had no issues at all. They of course will use your information for advertising purposes but in checking my credit reports I've found no discrepancies.

Comment: Given that Credit Karma is under a Consent Order (http://www.ftc.gov/system/files/documents/cases/1408creditkarmado.pdf), I believe this comment may mislead people into thinking there are and have been no issues with Credit Karma.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton I never said the company has no problems, I'm just sharing my experience, nothing wrong with that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the definition of safe. I'm sure they use your information for marketing purposes. Also, I found the scoring information grossly inaccurate on Credit Karma. Pulling the actually scores once a year from the actual agencies will be comprehensive and accurate.

Comment: Can you be more specific? The last time I pulled the real scores, they had a low/high range of 17, and Credit Karma was right in the middle.

Comment: The only score that matters in lending (mortgage, credit, etc.) is FICO. Experian, Equifax, and TransUnion use their own proprietary versions of these that banks and lenders reference when extending credit. Credit Karma, due either to its proprietary algorithm using different criteria, or an incomplete score factor aggregator to gather my info in order to generate a FICO, never generates a score that has remotely matched the above mentioned FICO scores. In any case, it's not worth tracking every month and I just do so once a year.